# How do I render the show view of Controller 'B' when I am in Controller 'A'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to render the `show` action of a `user`, from another controller `vanity`.

This is what my `Vanity` controller looks like:

```
class VanitiesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    if(v = Vanity.find_by_name(params[:vname]))
        redirect v.vain 
    else
      # If the vanity name can't be found, render a 404
      respond_to do |f|
        f.html { render :status => :not_found, :file => File.join(Rails.root, "public", "404.html") }
        f.xml  { head :not_found }
        f.any  { head :not_found }
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

As is, that does a redirect to `/users/:id/`. However, rather than redirecting I want to render that `show` action.

When I just do `render v.vain` I get this message:

```
Template is missing

Missing partial users/user with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/app/views"
```

I also tried `render :controller => :users, :action => :show` and that simply rendered the `:show` action for my `vanities` controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
render "/controller/action"
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 render :template => "b/show"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use

redirect_to :controller => '', :action =>''

with parameters: 
redirect_to :controller => '', :action =>'', :parameter => @variable